# Where should I look for cheap renting cars in USA?

Tags: usa, budget, car-rentals

I would like to rent a car in the USA from beginning of September for approximately 1 week. I would like to rent it in Niagara and give it back in New York. Where should i look for cheap opportunities? I know the major rental car companies, but maybe there is a local advice for something cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest http://www.3clickcarhire.com/

I tend to avoid having to rent cars, but the few times I have, I found these guys to be the cheapest. They source car hires from multiple providers and, consistently, for me, have been cheaper than renting with the individual providers themselves.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great. However, I tried to use Niagara as Pick up Location and various locations to drop off, and I couldn't find any available car.

Comment: Hm! Sorry about that. I just tried and couldn't get any deal for anywhere in the US (but I could get deals for elsewhere). I suspect their booking engine is having issues.

Comment: Could you please add detail to this about WHY you recommend it etc, rather than just giving a link.

Comment: Technically, I didn't recommend it, but suggested it. But, sure.