# Renting a car in Canada and drop it off in USA

Tags: usa, canada, car-rentals, new-york-city, montreal

I already asked a very similar questions [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/where-should-i-look-for-cheap-renting-cars-in-usa).

But this time I'm looking for a car for two weeks (end of August until first week of September). I want to pick it up in Montreal and give it back in New York.

Are there any cheap recommendations? I don't need any fancy things, just the cheapest alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hertz is showing me $900 CAD per week from the Montreal airport to JFK with an AAA discount (about $50 more without). That's a little under $900 USD, if that sounds affordable.